# How to find out efficiently the auto-generated id for a new object when using JPA?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, persistence, openjpa

I have an attribute which is annotated with @Id. The ID is going to be generated automatically when persisting the object. That means that the ID-value is not defined before I persist the object. After persisting it, it has an ID (in the database), but unfortunately the field still remains null as long as I don't reload it from the DB.
is there any easy way to find out the generated id? Or better: To configure that it will be written into the field?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The id gets assigned after the flush. Assuming the `Foo` entity has an `id` attribute annotated with the standard `@Id @GeneratedValue` annotations, the following code works:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
//...
em.persist(foo);
em.flush();
assert foo.getId() != null;
```

Comment: Great. That's exactly what I was looking for. :-)